# Cómo crear una lista de paths de archivos filtrados por su extensión jpg en un árbol de carpetas

Tags: python, lista, rutas

Quiero crear una lista de paths de todos los archivos jpg que existen en un árbol de carpetas. Estoy intentando con este código, pero todos los archivos sin importar la extensión los agrega a la lista con el formato "jpg". solo necesito agregar los JPG.

```
from pathlib import Path

ruta="C:\\Folder\\"
list = [ archivo.with_suffix(".jpg").as_posix() \
         for archivo in Path(ruta).glob("**/*")]

print(list)
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que con `Path(ruta).glob("**/*")` no estás *filtrando* nada, con lo que obtienes todos los ficheros del árbol. Después usas `archivo.with_suffix(".jpg")` que lo que hace es cambiar la extensión de todos los archivos por `.jpg`.

Para filtrar los archivos *.jpgs* debes indicarlo en `.glob()`:

```py
from pathlib import Path

ruta = Path("C:\\Folder\\")
jpgs = [ archivo.as_posix()
         for archivo in ruta.glob("**/*.jpg")]
print(jpgs)
```

Answer (score 1):

En esa función solo le estás indicando que transforme todos los archivos a formato `jpg`, no que te los filtre, para filtrarlos ponle una condicional a tu array

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

ruta="C:\\Folder\\"
list_ = [ archivo.with_suffix(".jpg").as_posix() \
         for archivo in Path(ruta).glob("**/*")
         if os.path.splitext(archivo)[1] == '.jpg']

print(list_)
```

Basicamente `splitext` regresa un `tuple` de dos elementos, donde el primero es el **nombre del archivo** y el segundo es la **extensión**.

Entonces si por ejemplo `arr = os.path.splitext('docs/file.txt')`Esto te regresará `arr = ('docs/file', '.txt')`

**NOTA IMPORTANTE**

`list` es una palabra reservada de python, si llamas a una variable `list` **estás sobreescribiendo ese método de python!**

por ejemplo intenta

```
a = list(('a', 'b'))
print(a) #imprime una lista ['a', 'b']
list = ['x', 'y']
a = list(('a', 'b')) #arrojará un error porque ahora list no es una función, es una lista.
```

Por lo que nunca uses palabras reservadas de python.

Si quieres dejarla como `list` se sugiere que le añadas un guion bajo al final para diferenciarlo de las palabras reservadas, así `list_`  esto no sobreescribirá nada.

Comment: Es mejor no mezclar innecesariamente `os.path` con `pathlib`. En la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#correspondence-to-tools-in-the-os-module) hay una tabla de equivalencias. Añado una respuesta para ilustrarlo.